# Python, "replace" module using

Tags: python-3.x, methods, replace

I just started learning Python. I ran into a problem when I wanted to write a small sample code using the "replace" module. Here is my code:

---

```
char_arr = "Dün değil evvelsi gün"

vowel_in_tr = "aeıioöuü"
for i in vowel_in_tr: 
    for k in char_arr:                          #search a vowel
        if k == i:                              #if found a vowel
new = char_arr.replace(str(k),"i")  #change the vowel to "i"

print(new) #Output is new char_arr
```

---

I want to if my char_arr variable is "Dün değil evvelsi gün", then my output is "Din diğil ivvilsi gin" . But instead of that, my output is "Din değil evvelsi gin."

How I coding this example correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
char_arr = "Dün değil evvelsi gün"

vowel_in_tr = "aeıioöuü"
for i in char_arr:
    if i in vowel_in_tr:
        char_arr = char_arr.replace(i, 'i')

print(char_arr)
```

Result: Din diğil ivvilsi gin

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting `new = char_arr.replace(str(k), "i")` it is not keeping that replaced string throughout. char_arr is not being updated. Here is some code that will fix your problem.

```
char_arr = "Dün değil evvelsi gün"
new_string_arr = []

vowel_in_tr = "aeıioöuü"
for ch in char_arr: # walk through the char_arr
    if ch in vowel_in_tr: # if the character is in the vowel array
        new_string_arr.append('i')  # add an i to the new string "i"
    else: # otherwise
        new_string_arr.append(ch) # add the original character

# join together the new array with nothing in between characters
new_string = ''.join(new_string_arr)

print(new_string) #Output is new_string
```

Comment: The answer from Yakir Tsuberi is also correct. His just replaces the string "in place" while mine makes a new one and doesn't mess with the old string.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the replaced string in another variable:

```
char_arr = "Dün değil evvelsi gün"
vowel_in_tr = "aeıioöuü"

result = char_arr

for a in char_arr: 
  if a in vowel_in_tr:
    result = result.replace(a , 'i')

print (result)
```

It wasn't working because a "new" string was being assigned to your variable each time you use `new = char_arr.replace(str(k),"i")`, since `char_arr` value is `Dün değil evvelsi gün`.